# Заменить слово в документах *.dot или *.dotx

Tags: php

Как заметить через PHP все слова `#VALUE#` в документе (*.dot или *.dotx)?

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с любыми Word документами необходима библиотека SOAP. А какую библиотеку для обработки документа использовать решать Вам, их много. Довольно популярна [PHPDOCX](http://www.phpdocx.com/)

Comment: вот именно не могу найти подходящий они все работают документами doc.docx. тотже PHPDOCX, а мне нужно только (*.dot или *.dotx)

Comment: может кто-то работал через PHP с этими типами документов?

Comment: @Николай Сарры, Пожалуйста, давайте ответ на вопрос, а не ссылку на то, что, кстати, не решает вопрос.

Comment: http://файлообменник.рф/8sm5bzq6wivk.html

Comment: [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP)?

Answer (score 1):

Все новые форматы документов Office, основанные на XML — это просто ZIP-архивы. Если всё, что вам надо — это сгенерировать документ по шаблону и заменить некоторый текст, то есть простое топорное решение: создаёте документ DOCX, в нужных местах расставляете плейсхолдеры типа `#VALUE#`, распаковываете, заменяете, упаковываете.

Это тривиально делается программно, не нужно никаких сложных сторонних решений и отдельных шаблонов DOTX. XML-ки можно хоть обрабатывать через DOM, хоть пропускать через `str_replace`, хоть класть как отдельный скрипт и шаблонизировать с помощью PHP — как душе угодно, потому что шаблон фиксированный.

Вот если вам нужно что-то реально сложное, что не ограничивается заменой текста и повтором блоков — тогда да, можно смотреть в сторону сложных инструментов.

P.S. Ответ написан в предположении, что вам нужно из DOTX получить DOCX с заменённым текстом. Если вам нужно из "шаблонного шаблона" DOTX получить просто шаблон DOTX, то операции те же самые, только расширение файла другое.

Comment: Вы уверены, что там не нужно будет проставить ещё и корректные кросс-рефы где-нибудь? Как-то нечестно применять замену текста вместо сериализации объектной модели.

Comment: @VladD *Заменять* простой текст абсолютно безопасно, никакие ссылки никуда не нужны (куда ссылки?). Если *повторять* — уже есть риск нарваться на сложную структуру, смотреть надо внимательнее. Представьте, что это шаблон HTML — с помощью `str_replace` нельзя изменять документ в общем случае, но во многих частных прекрасно работает. Для случая одиночных плейсхолдеров без повторов я бы точно не беспокоился. Экранировать только надо, если плюнуть на XML DOM/SAX.

Comment: Ну, вот вам (гипотетический) пример. Допустим, в текстовых секциях `#VALUE#` — это просто часть текста, а в секциях с метаданными имеет особое значение. Простой текстовый поиск не различит эти два случая. (По поводу ссылок — допустим, вам нужно в отдельной таблице расставить ссылки (например, номер символа) на места, где заканчивается страница. Вставляя текст, вы инвалидируете старые ссылки.)

Comment: Я не настаиваю на том, что это возможно для офисовского формата (я его не знаю). Но работать в обход объектной структуры кажется мне хрупким решением.

Comment: @VladD Предполагается, что шаблон у вас свой, один, фиксированный, перед заменой вы убедились, что уникальный плейсхолдер является уникальным плейсхолдером, а после замены убедились, что документ не сломался. Разумеется, для сложных случаев это плохой подход, но когда надо в документе поменять один плейсхолдер, тащить монструозную библиотеку — это, по-моему, лишнее. Скажем, я бы не тащил Razor, если мне нужно в консольном приложении на C# сгенерировать HTML с голым списком — я бы просто наконкатенировал текст. Хотя ведь ужас: валидации нет, экранировать всё вручную...

Comment: Именно поэтому я голосовал за ваш ответ. Но всё же, интересно и скалируемое решение.